# printing a mirrored word using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

i need to write a method that takes in a string as a parameter and prints the word in mirrored form. for example, "hello" should return "helloolleh". I have to use recursion and cannot use for loops. Here is my code so far:

```
public static String printMirrored(String str)
{
    if(str == null || str.equals(""))

    {
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        return str + printMirrored(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

My output is "helloellollolooolleh" which obviously has some extra things in there. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't understand the use of recursion. Basic Loops are so much easier and convenient

Comment: Recursion is a fundamental concept. It is very important to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `str.charAt(0)` at the beginning instead of `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is about being the utmost lazy person delegating the rest to a recursive clone.
So on "Hello", take only the "H", get the mirrored result of "ello" and surround it on both ends with an "H".

Answer (score 2):

Wrote this real quick. Should do exactly what you want but if you have any questions please let me know.

```
String word = "hello";
System.out.println(reverseWord(word, word.length()));

public static String reverseWord(String word, int length) {
    if(length == 0)
        return word;
    else
        return reverseWord(word + word.charAt(length - 1), length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Just did. Prints out "helloolleh" just like requested. Could change the function name because we are actually mirroring the word not just reversing. Might not be the best implementation but this is the first thing that came to mind with the OP specifications.  
  
Edit: Just saw your ruby solution. Pretty much the same except I start from lenght-1 and stop at 0 and you do the opposite.

Comment: Hm, I didn't get the logic at all, had to run the code. Apparently yes, it does work. Get a +1 :)

Comment: Also, I took the liberty and fixed a typo in your code that was driving me nuts :)

Comment: hehe be my guest. Also your ruby solution was good too and I think it used kind of the same logic.

Comment: yeah, I understand your solution now. Indeed logic is similar.

Answer (score 0):

use [StringBuilder.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29)

Comment: I assume it's a homework, so use of stdlib is traditionally forbidden.